# How to Impersonate user in G Suite Using .Net API

Tags: .net, google-workspace

I am using Google DRIVE API from .NET google client library and wanted to impersonate user from service account . I have read many other users facing same issue but none of fix worked for me. Below is detail.

1) Create service account and enabled DWD
2) Downloaded JSON file
3) added client id with API scopes which i have to consume in manage API client access
4) added permission to shard drive 
5) Using below code to create service and upload/get data from google drive

```
        string [] scopes=new string[]
         {
             driveservice.scope.drive,
             drivesercie.scope.drivefile,
             driveservice.scope.driveappdata,
             driveservice.scope.drivemetadata       
         };
GoogleCredential cred;
using(var stream=new FileStream(Keyfilepath,Filemode.open,FileAccess.Read))
{
    cred=GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).createdscoped(scopes).createwithuser(UserEmail);
}
```

This code is working fine with the same code but I have just changed/updated the API client scopes after that getting below error.

What I have tried.

1) Created new service account and client ID for the same project but getting same error.(Waited for 24 hours after done DWD and updated API scopes)
2) Created new project and new service account with client ID (Enabled DWD) but getting same error.

Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.", Uri:""

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try an alternative code using P12 key.

```
            String serviceAccoutnEmail = "serviceAccount@emailAddress";
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"pathToYourKeyFile.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccoutnEmail)
            {
                User = "user@toimpersonate",
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, }
                }.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

However, I don't think there is a problem with your code.

- Ensure the scopes authorized in the Admin Console(Manage API Client    Access) are the same you're including on your credential from the    code.
- Reauthorize the Client name in the Admin Console. There must be no spaces in the text filed for Client Name and Scopes, as a security    measure if there is any space the Admin Console will not correct this    and the API call made from this client will fail.
- Ensure that Drive API is enabled for your new Project on the API dashboard of the GCP console.